# Call different Service api's based on the entity object in spring framework

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, service, class-hierarchy

I am working on a web service application designed using spring framework, where I have different entity classes(ActivityA,ActivityB,ActivityC...) which inherit from a base class "activity"

Now I have written different service api's in service layer for the base class and all the child classes. (to name, ActivityService,ActivityAService,ActivityBService,ActivityCService..)

All the methods which operate similar for each activity are put in service api of base class(ActivityService) and rest in their respective services.

I generally know which object I am working on, and I call the respective service api. But in a particular case I have the activity object(don't know of which child class it is) and have to write a method which is different for all entity objects.

PROBLEM : Is there a way,I can call different service's based on the entity object I have.(the object I have is of entity, not service and I cant do any hard coding to get Service object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But in a particular case I have the activity object(don't know of which child class it is) and have to write a method which is different for all entity objects.

Just make the base class abstract and define an abstract method that each sub class has to implement:

```
public abstract class ActivityService{
    public abstract Foo processEntity(Entity entity);
}
```

> PROBLEM : Is there a way,I can call different service's based on the entity object I have.(the object I have is of entity, not service and I cant do any hard coding to to )

This is a situation you should try to avoid. Usually, you should only send an entity to a service that knows what to do with it, and not to a bunch of services, one of which is in charge. But what I'd do is use a dispatcher service that keeps a map of classes that the services are in charge of. It uses logic like this:

```
private Map<Class<? extends Entity>,
    Class<? extends ActivityService>> serviceMap =
        new ConcurrentHashMap<Class<? extends Entity>,
                              Class<? extends ActivityService>>();
private ApplicationContext context;
private ActivityService getServiceForEntity(Entity e){
    Class<? extends Entity> entityClass = e.getClass();
    Class<? extends ActivityService> serviceClass =
        serviceMap.get(entityClass);
    if(serviceClass==null){
        for(Map.Entry<Class<? extends Entity>,
                      Class<? extends ActivityService>> entry :
            serviceMap.entrySet()){
            if(entry.getKey().isAssignableFrom(entityClass)){
                serviceClass = entry.getValue();
                break;
            }
        }
        if(serviceClass==null){
            // throw a suitable exception
        }
        serviceMap.put(entityClass, serviceClass);
    }
    return context.getBean(serviceClass);
}
```

Comment: Thanks S.P. I cant override the method, coz as i said I have only entity object, not the service object. Well the solution given above to get the corresponding service class of given object is what shud be done perhaps.. but I was hoping(m new to spring) there would be some way Spring could relate the entities with their corresponding service...!!

Comment: @shail *as i said I have only entity object, not the service object* Oh, I thought it was the other way around. No, Spring doesn't know your application's architecture, so it can't do that for you. It's your job when you build an app to make sure each entity gets passed to the correct service. Usually you would have one controller per entity type, and it would have the correct service injected.

Comment: I got an entity CONTENT, which can have different activities. As I mentioned above, I have designed different activities as child class of a base class activity. Now I generally use the respective controller for operations on any activity. But I have a functionality to implement to copy CONTENT( that means i also need to create a new copy of all the activities associated to that content and associate them with the newly created(copied) content).

Comment: All activities have foreign keys for CONTENT, based on which I get what activities are to be copied, but the type of object(which subclass) returned is not known before runtime.. The service api's of all the activities have there copy method(internal copy method is differs allot for each activity). I thought I can use method overriding and call a copy method for each object returned (when I fetch activities based on content)

Comment: Only way it looks possible now is to get the corresponding service api from entity object as you have explained above. Knowing the whole scenario now,do you think there can be any better different approach..? pls let me know. Very Thankful to you.

Comment: @shail I'm afraid there is no other way